# Node.JS is returning only a part of records for the MySQL "WHERE IN" clause

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, http, get

I am trying to execute the following `GET` function.

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/sportfolioimages/getbyportfoliolist?portfolioid_list=69,70,71
```

My code is in Node.js, check below.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: prop.get('server.host'),
  user: prop.get("server.username"),
  password: prop.get("server.password"),
  port: prop.get("server.port"),
  database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.getSellerPortfolioItemImagesByPortfolioList = (event, context, callback) => {

  const params = event.queryStringParameters;


  if (!params || portfolioid_list == null) {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    var response = errorCodes.missing_parameters;
    callback(null, response)
  }
  else {

    const portfolioid_list = event.queryStringParameters.portfolioid_list;
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    const sql = "SELECT * FROM peresia.seller_portfolio_item_images WHERE idseller_portfolio_item IN (?)";
      con.execute(sql, [portfolioid_list], function (err, result) {
      console.log(sql);
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          var response = errorCodes.internal_server_error;
          callback(null, response);
        }
        else {
          var response = {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify(result),
            "isBase64Encoded": false
          };
          callback(null, response)
        }
      });


  }
};
```

My code always returns whatever the values that is at the first of the list of values in my call. Since my list of values are `69,70,71` it always returns only the records that matched `69` and and no records are returned for `70` and `71` even though there are records in the database.

So for an example, below is the result I get when the above `GET` function is executed,.

```
[
    {
        "idseller_portfolio_item_images": 22,
        "idseller_portfolio_item": 69,
        "image_url": "https://database.com/portfolio/IMG_20211020_114254-1634730049335.jpg"
    },
    {
        "idseller_portfolio_item_images": 23,
        "idseller_portfolio_item": 69,
        "image_url": "https://database.com/portfolio/IMG_20211020_114254-1634730049335.jpg"
    },
    {
        "idseller_portfolio_item_images": 31,
        "idseller_portfolio_item": 69,
        "image_url": "https://peresia3.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/portfolio/IMG_20211020_114254-1634730049335.jpg"
    },
    {
        "idseller_portfolio_item_images": 32,
        "idseller_portfolio_item": 69,
        "image_url": "https://database/portfolio/IMG_20211020_114254-1634730049335.jpg"
    }
]
```

If I just run the MySQL code directly in the database, I will be able to get the full set of records without an issue.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/1219) you will need something like this

```js
const portfolioid_list = [69,70,71];

const sql = "SELECT * FROM peresia.seller_portfolio_item_images WHERE idseller_portfolio_item IN (?,?,?)";
      con.execute(sql, portfolioid_list, function (err, result) { ...
```

This way you can dynamically build your query. [reference](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/1266#issuecomment-750585920)

```js
const portfolioid_list = event.queryStringParameters.portfolioid_list.split(",");  //converts to a list ["69", "70", "71"]
    
portfolioidValsPlaceHolders=Array(portfolioid_list.length).fill("?").join();
const sql = "SELECT * FROM peresia.seller_portfolio_item_images WHERE idseller_portfolio_item IN ("+portfolioidValsPlaceHolders+")"; 
      con.execute(sql, portfolioid_list, function (err, result) { ...
```

Comment: Okay, but how am I supposed to know the exact length of the list? Seems a bug isnt it.. I will check the git now.

Comment: you can parse the query parameter string in to a list then using the length of the list you can build the no of '?' needed in the sql statement. just a suggestion

Comment: Can you help me out with that? I have very little knowledge on Node.js

Comment: `const portfolioid_list = event.queryStringParameters.portfolioid_list.split(",");  //converts to a list ["69", "70", "71"]`
`let sql = "SELECT * FROM peresia.seller_portfolio_item_images WHERE idseller_portfolio_item IN (";`
`sql += "?,".repeat(portfolioid_list.length);  //adding the "?"`
`sql = sql.substring(0, sql.length - 1); //remove the last unwanted ","`
`sql += ")";  //now the sql is complete`
there is probably a more elegant way of doing this